# Non-html output on a specific route using Next.js?

Tags: next.js

I have one route in a dynamic Next.js application where I just want to output SVG. It's not a static SVG but a dynamic SVG output that I'm programmatically creating based on values in a backend API. But I *just* want the SVG output and not the wrapping `html`, `body` etc that I'm using elsewhere.

Any ideas how can have a route that just outputs what's on that page?

Comment: Is the calculation of the svg's values based on the url params? Or in which way is it dynamic?

Comment: @tstrmn tried to clarify my questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's an [API route](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction), then simply something like this will work:

```js
export default function handler(req, res) {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/svg+xml');
  // create your dynamic svg here...
  const svg = `<svg>...</svg>`;
  res.status(200).end(svg);
}
```

If it's a page, then you can do this hack:

```js
export default function Foo() {
  return null;
}

export async function getServerSideProps({ req, res }) {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/svg+xml');
  // create your dynamic svg here...
  const svg = `<svg>...</svg>`;
  res.end(svg);
  return { props: {} };
}
```

[image: Open in StackBlitz]